# Once I active Jetpack, I cannot open any dashboard pages any more

Tags: wordpress, plugins, jetpack

I have an issue when I try to install Jetpack on my wordpress site.

When the installation finished, I clicked "active" to active the Jetpack plugin, but I could not open any dashboard pages anymore.

I have already removed all other plugins and reinstalled Jetpack many times, but I still have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

What did I do is:

1. Add the following code in wp-config.php file to enable debugging.

// Enable WP_DEBUG mode

define('WP_DEBUG', true);

// Enable Debug logging to the /wp-content/debug.log file

define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);

// Disable display of errors and warnings

define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);

@ini_set('display_errors',0);

// Use dev versions of core JS and CSS files (only needed if you are modifying these core files)
define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true);

2. Open [your domain]/wp-content/debug.log to open the log
3. What did I find is:
   PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 41943040 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 30720 bytes) in /hsphere/local/home/.../wp-admin/includes/media.php on line 2765
4. To slove this problem, i have added the following code in wp-config.php file

   define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');

I don't really know the reason, but it works for me.